# Why does my GUI disappear as soon as I initialize an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, imageicon, null-layout-manager

So i wanna program a Tic Tac Toe game in java.

Now uppon clicking a button, i wanna set the Image of the Button to either "cross" or "circle", but as soon as a type following code, the buttons disappear until i hover over them, then they return.

```
ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon("Cross.png");
```

[What it looks like without the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIMrg.png)
[What it looks like with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIHZM.png)

[Project Structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BsqU.png)

Comment: We don’t have enough code to address your problem.  The most likely answer is that the image wasn’t loaded, either because you are running from a .jar (in which case reosurces are not files at all), or because the current directory is not what you assume it to be (which is why relative filenames are not advisable).  Edit your question and show the code that uses the image, and show us the structure of your project.

Comment: How do i put in images here, i cant just paste

Comment: Show your code as code-formatted text, not as an image please. Best to check out the [ask], [tour] and [help] links too.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre]. Hot link to an image or create one in the code.

Comment: Please, no key information in comments. Again, [edit] your question and use comments to notify us that you've updated the question.

Comment: I hope that you're not using null layouts or absolute positioning (`.setBounds(...)`)

Comment: I did in fact use null layot for the window, i saw that on youtube

Comment: *"How do i put in images here, i cant just paste"* You need a higher rep. to add images. I edited and *could* have embedded those, but they do not show anything that could not be described in words, which are preferable.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** learn to code from youtube videos. I have seen too much bad advice, like what you're receiving, like dangerous database access open to SQL injection and a whole host of other horrors. Just don't do it. Serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did in fact use null layot for the window

That's the problem. For a 3 x 3 grid, I'd use a `GridLayout`. See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for further details.

Comment: We keep telling people, on and on and on and on again. 1+